# transform all columns in a data frame with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
set.seed(9782)
df1 <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(100, mean=123, sd=6),
                  X2 = rnorm(100, 567, 21),
                  X3 = rnorm(100, 783, 82))
```

I want to rescale all the columns of df1. I can do it with the following code:

```
means <- apply(df1, 2, mean)
sds   <- apply(df1, 2, sd)  
df1Rescaled <- data.frame(t(t(t(t(df1) - means)) / sds))
```

How can I do the same with dplyr?

Comment: Seriously, why not just `scale(df1)`?

Comment: related http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-faster-scale-function/

Comment: @rawr but there are no pipes in it and it wasn't posted by Hadley :(

Comment: @DavidArenburg anything is possible in R `scale(df1) %>% identity`. oh, I didn't see your edit :{

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `scale`

```
df1New <- df1 %>%
            mutate_each(funs(scale))
```